# Setting source filename in C++ target

Tags: c++, antlr, filenames, antlr4, preprocessor

I have a code preprocessor which inserts a `#line` directive in the source code. The directive contains a filename, line number, and character position. I have a lexer rule for the `#line` directive that calls a function called `newFile`. The `newFile` function sets the lexer line number and character position. But, I don't see a way to set the source name. There are functions for getting the source name, but not setting it. I tried setting the input stream source name, but that didn't seem to work (I have an `errorListener` that gets the filename from `recognizer->getInputStream()->getSourceName()` but it always returns the initial filename).

My code is (C++ target):

```
preprocessor pp(_defines, _incpaths);
ANTLRInputStream input(pp.preprocess(filename));
myLexer lexer(&input);
CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
myParser parser(&tokens);
antlr4::tree::ParseTree* tree = parser.start();
```

And, the `newFile` code is:

```
void myLexer::newFile (std::string newFilename, int newLine, int newPos)
{
    static_cast<ANTLRInputStream*>(_input)->name = newFilename;   // doesn't work
    setLine(newLine);
    setCharPositionInLine(newPos);
}
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in functionality like that. Keep this information in a separate structure and manage changes there. The input stream name is just a convenient feature, which is not flexible enough for that kind of processing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info. I tried a few different ways to store file/location information in a separate structure, but it quickly got overly complex.

I resolved the problem by taking advantage of Antlr's line tracking functionality. I stored the filename in a list, then encoded the list index of the filename into the line number.

```
int fileIndex = filename_list.size();
filename_list.append(filename);
int line = (fileIndex << 20) + newLine;
setLine(line);
setCharPositionInLine(newPos);
```

Then, in the errorListener, or AST builder, it's easy to access the filename:

```
void errorListener::syntaxError(Recognizer* recognizer......)
{
   int fileIndex = line >> 20;
   line &= 0xFFFFF;
```